# How to enforce loading order of some non-managed classes in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, classloader

We are overriding some classes from the application's dependencies. Those classes are not managed classes in Spring. Sometimes they are loaded in right order and are being picked but sometimes they're not.

As per Spring boot documentations, classes/jar in lib folder will be loaded first and then those in nested in 'classes' folder. I placed those overridden classes in 'classes' folder but some of them are not being picked.

I understand one way to do this is to create a customized jar of the dependency itself and replace the classes but is there any other way to enforce the order of loading them?

We are using **Spring Boot 1.4.0**

As an example, consider we have a third party jar file named **xyz.jar**. There is a class in that jar file named **com.something.A.class**. Because we needed to support extra operations we've created a class with the same package name but in our source folder. Now we want to be able to change the order of the classes so that our version (the one we created) gets loaded last and the original one gets replaced.

To start up our application, we run the jar file that is produced by spring-boot.

Just to mention again that there is no error or anything, it's just that the classes that we created sometimes, some of them, aren't loaded memory and vice versa. And those not loaded are replaced by the original ones

Comment: Would be good if you worded your question more specifically. Show code, errors, maybe your build configuration?

Comment: @Strelok I have edited and added more info. However, there isn't much more to say on this. There is no specific configuration or anything as any person familiar with Spring boot should be fine. Thanks